# converting date string to date format

Tags: c#, string, date

I have tried out as many suggestions as I've found on Stackoverflow, but not getting the desired result. Any help would be much appreciated.

My date string is "04-Dec-2013 14:14:02.143" and I want to convert this exactly as into `DateTime` format.

This was the last suggestion I tried:

```
String MyString;                            
MyString = "04-Dec-2013 14:14:02.143";

DateTime MyDateTime;
MyDateTime = new DateTime();

MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                           null);
```

However, I keep getting the undesired result of "04/12/2013 14:14:02" rather want it to be "04-Dec-2013 14:14:02.143".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's the online Microsoft webpage for how to format DateTime : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should read about `DateTime` struct. **It has not have any format info attached**, it's just a plain number representing point in time.

The format come into play when you try to get `string` representation of the data, using `ToString(format)` method.

Use the format string every time you're calling `ToString` to get the date in the format you want it to be:

```
var stringDateRespresentation = dateValue.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

To make things easier you should pass plain, non-formatted `DateTime` instances all around and change it into `string` using `ToString` method only when it's being presented to the user.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.. that clears my understanding of DateTime.. However, seems I still have a problem as the end goal is not to present date&time to user but to INSERT into a database which has a DATETIME field. I am reading date and time into 2 string variables from an array, and hoping to combine these to values into a single datetime value and insert into DB. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

@MarcinJuraszek has better answer on this question, but it does not solve the problem of different datetime patterns, because of what great SO users mark other questions as duplicate.

```
        string MyString = "Dec-12-2013 14:14:02.143";
        CultureInfo ukCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        ukCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString, ukCulture.DateTimeFormat);
        string QbDate = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

To solve the issue of different date-time patterns override any date pattern of any culture

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MarcinJuraszek the format comes into picture when you convert it back to string. The format you mentioned in ParseExact is for the parsing. i.e. How will MyString be parsed to create a DateTime object.

See below example just so you understand how the ParseExact format string is used.

If you use MyDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:ss:mm.fff"); instead (see I swapped mm and ss) in ParseExact you will get "12/4/2013 2:02:14 PM" instead of "12/4/2013 2:14:02 PM"